# How to update tox environments when setup.cfg files change?

Tags: python, tox

How can I get `tox` to automatically recreate its virtualenvs with the new dependencies whenever I make a change to my package's `setup.cfg` file?

Normally a Python package would list its dependencies using the setuptools `install_requires` setting in its `setup.cfg`:

```ini
[options]
install_requires =
    google-auth-oauthlib
    PyJWT
    pyramid>=2.0.0
```

Then if using `tox` you'd list your *test* dependencies using the [`deps` setting](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-deps) in `tox.ini`:

```ini
[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov >= 3.5
```

If you make a change to the `deps` in `tox.ini` then the next time you run `tox` it'll notice the change and will recreate the virtualenv installing the new deps.

But if you make a change to the dependencies in the `setup.cfg` file `tox` will not notice this and won't recreate the virtualenv. You have to manually run `tox --recreate` to force recreation. Is there any way to get `tox` to automatically recreate the virtualenv when `setup.cfg` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tox-recreate`](https://github.com/hypothesis/tox-recreate) is a simple `tox` plugin that watches for changes to your `setup.cfg` file. Whenever you run a `tox` command it'll trigger `tox` to recreate the virtualenv if your `setup.cfg` has changed. To use it just add `tox-recreate` to the [`requires` setting](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-requires) in your `tox.ini` file:

```ini
[tox]
requires = tox-recreate
```